# '; expected' error in define() function in PHP even though I already have it

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make simple PHP codes and encounter this error. However, when I run test it, everything is fine.

When I try to make a constant variable using define(), I put it like this.

```
define('NAME', 'Yoshi');
```

And the error appears next to the semicolon is: '; expected'.
Here is my full code.

```
<?php
// index.php

    define('NAME', 'Yoshi');
    $age = 30;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title> my PHP </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Something here</h1>

        <div><?php echo NAME; ?></div>
        <div><?php echo $age; ?></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unable to replicate the issue - https://3v4l.org/L6AhT

Comment: Same, are you sure the code you have given us is the same ?

Comment: It's the same codes I typed in VS Code. Imo, I think there is something wrong with VS Code instead of my program. I read many documentations and these syntax should be correct.
https://imgur.com/jAO6UlX

Comment: Does the error appear in VS Code or on the webpage??? if it's in VS Code, get a better extension for PHP Linting ;)

Comment: I am using php.exe from xampp in the folder php. I put its location in setting.json as php.validate.executablePath variable. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Sometimes Visual Studio Code make funny things like that. I have been working on a file, an error appears, I corrected it, but the error marking stays until I save the file... Maybe something similar happens to you ;)

Answer (score -1):

When the **PHP Intellisense** extension is installed on VSCode you have to find these errors.